# EF6 codefirst slow startup

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, ef-code-first

I'm in a scenario WPF MVVM EF code first. 
All start my application I have to initialize the two databases, but lose 10 seconds each time to do everything. there is a way to speed up?

```
        private void InitDb()
    {
        var sednaComuniContext = new SednaComuniContext();         
        sednaComuniContext.Database.Initialize(false);//slowly

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Ditta) || Ditta == "BaseDb") return;
        var sednaContext = new SednaContext(dbHelper.CreateConnectionString(Ditta));
        sednaContext.Database.Initialize(false);//slowly
    }
```

SednaComuniContext:

```
public class SednaComuniContext : DbContext,IContext 
    {
    public static DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    static string _connection;

    public SednaComuniContext()
        : base(CreateConnectionString())
    {

    }

    private static string CreateConnectionString()
    {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper();

        return dbHelper.CreateConnectionString("ArchiviComuni");
    }

    public SednaComuniContext(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    {
         _connection = connString;

        if (!Database.Exists())
        {
            Database.Initialize(true); 
        }
    }

    public DbSet<ArticoliFamiglia> ArticoliFamiglia { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticoliGruppo> ArticoliGruppo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Articoli> Articoli { get; set; }


     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SednaComuniContext, Configuration>());

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

     }
}
```

SednaContext:

```
public class SednaContext : DbContext,IContext //IDbContext
{
    public static DatabaseHelper dbHelper;


    static string _connection;

    public SednaContext()
       : base(_connection)
    {


    }
    public SednaContext(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    {

            _connection = connString;


    }
    public DbSet<ArticoliFamiglia> ArticoliFamiglia { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticoliFamigliaImpostazioni> ArticoliFamigliaImpostazioni { get; set; }


      public DbSet<ArticoliGruppo> ArticoliGruppo { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SednaContext, Configuration>());

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
}
```

Can an entity migration be used for that?

Comment: Practice a little with formatting  and the `{}` button. This is not readable.

Comment: Now I just formatted :D

Comment: If I see correctly you use c# 4.0 meaning that the EF version we are talking about would be EF 4.4, right? And another thing: the problem occurres only at startup of the application or at another parts as well?

Comment: hello, I use c # 5, and f 6.1. slow only at startup, when I initialize for each db =(

Answer (score 1):

Since the Entity Framework team has moved to Entity Framework 6 to the EntityFramework.dll the initial load of the database slowed down considerably, some of these problems were fixed but building a model with 2 entities at a console project takes 4-5 seconds for me as well. See this open item describing part of this problem:

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2298

The only workaround for this would be a loading screen where you show the users some fancy progress bar and display terms like loading this and that important part of the application.